# How should holy objects be buried?

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, genizah-storage

I understand *shemos* must be buried. Are there any restrictions on the manner or location of burial? (For example — just some ideas off the top of my head — need it be in a container which is then buried? any particular kind of container? Need it be buried somewhere specific, e.g. in a cemetery? Need it be placed rather then dumped into the hole in the ground? And any other details.)

Answer (score 3):

Excerpt from [Beth Hagenizah](http://www.bethgenizah.com/8.html):

> What is the proper way to perform genizah?
>
> Worn out sifrei torah should be placed in earthenware vessels and then
>   buried (Megillah 26b). Placing them inside these vessels forestalls
>   the decomposition of the sifrei torah for a long time. Indeed it is a
>   tragedy that Hashem’s name becomes obliterated, even in an indirect
>   way, and the mitzvah commands us to delay their decay for as long as
>   possible. They should be buried near a talmid chacham, or at least
>   near someone who studied halacha and other basic Torah.
>
> …
>
> The Mishnah Berurah (154:22, 24) quotes only the Pri Megadim,
>   accepting that printed seforim, even those bearing Hashem’s name, do
>   not have the full level of sanctity of hand-written seforim; he does
>   not even mention the disputing opinions. My impression is that this is
>   the practice usually followed by those who bury genizah: hand-written
>   Sifrei Torah, mezuzos, tefillin, megillos and naviim are specially
>   packed before burial in earthenware, wood, or glass containers;
>   whereas worn-out, printed seforim are simply placed in bags or
>   cardboard boxes and buried.

I suggest reading the article as it contains some general rules about what is considered *shaimos*, generally. I know this has been addressed in a several M.Y. questions, but this is a condensed format, worthwhile reading in light of the scandal that the linked web page mentions. Improperly disposed shaimos is, sadly, still a big problem, esp. considering that DEC and towns place dumping restrictions.

Personally, when 2 of my relatives were buried, some of the attendants "dumped" shaimos in the grave next to the coffin, and I have seen people who wait at the cemetery with their shaimos and follow a funeral group as they go to the grave. I think this may be halchically problematic if the family hasn't given permission for anyone to do this, and I'm surprised that this is allowed.

Comment: Frankly, I would be happy to know that some sefarim, preferably not valuable ones, were interred with my guf, although I'd like to grow old before I have to worry about that.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - You and others may be happy about it. Nonetheless, the grave is the personal property of the family, and others cannot, AFIK, just put anything in there w/o your or the family's permission.

Comment: I agree and understand.

Answer (score 2):

A recent [article](https://www.jewishlinknj.com/features/26483-where-do-good-books-go-when-they-die) ("Where Do Good Books Go When They Die?
") in Jewish Link of New Jersey provides interesting details

- The *sheimot* need to be buried in a way to preserve them as long as possible, which is accomplished by wrapping them up in polyethylene bags and lining the hole
- There are legal and environmental constraints since ideally large quantities of paper would be recycled
- They are buried in cheap plots of land, far from cities
- Surprisingly to me, people get *hechsherim* for burying *sheimot*

See the relevant details below and the full article for related details on synagogue policies as it relates to *sheimot*

> All this sheimot must be buried in a way that preserves it as long as
>   possible, since the point is to postpone its disintegration. Rabbi
>   Taplin explains: “When sheimos gets buried, it needs to be done in a
>   way that is the least damaging to the sefarim and other holy objects
>   we bury. We put the sefarim and papers in polyethylene bags because
>   that preserves them the most. We also line the hole in which the
>   burial takes place.”
>
> “People think, ‘Oh what’s the big deal? You just open up a hole, put
>   in the sheimos and you’re done,’” says Rabbi Taplin, “but it is not
>   that simple.” Besides for the halachic aspects, sheimot burial must be
>   done legally, which is made complicated by the Department of
>   Environmental Protection. The DEP is not enthusiastic about the burial
>   of large quantities of paper because they want to recycle it, and
>   therefore they require special permits that are difficult to access.
>   In fact, there have been a number of scandals by other sheimot
>   companies in the past where sheimot was dumped in landfills and other
>   illegal areas. Rabbi Taplin explains that 1866shaimos “has worked for
>   23 years with the DEP to bury sheimos according to law.”
>
> Purchasing land to bury sheimot is also expensive, which is why Rabbi
>   Taplin does not want to mention exactly where the sheimot is buried.
>   He worries that it would invite trespassers who would try to bury
>   their sheimot on his plots. The DEP does not allow burial in heavily
>   populated areas, and the land is cheaper away from population, so the
>   plots are not nearby.
>
> Just as Jews confirm meat is kosher through a hechsher, people also
>   use hechsheirim to sanction halachic sheimot burial. 1866shaimos has
>   two hechsherim, one from a local rav in Lakewood, Rabbi Shlomo Zalman
>   Friedman, the other from the Satmar beis din. Rabbi Taplin explains:
>   “We live in Lakewood so we used a local rav, who knows us. Regarding
>   Satmar, we are not officially affiliated with Satmar. However, the
>   Satmar community in Williamsburg is one of our biggest customers; they
>   give us four or five trailer loads of sheimos a year. Even though we
>   have our own local hashgacha, they wanted their own beis din to also
>   give a hashgacha; they are exacting and have very high standards.”
>   Rabbi Taplin says that they have also gone in front of other
>   communities’ batei din (rabbinic courts) to prove their kosher sheimot
>   practices, although those communities don’t all officially give out
>   hechsherim as Satmar did.

Comment: There was a scandal recently in Israel of people stealing invalid Mezuzot out of Sheimot "drop boxes" rolling them up again and reselling them. Just another reason you may want a Hekhsher on the operation.