# What is the proper way to dispose of a worn or soiled religious garment?

Tags: clothing, genizah-storage, religious-articles

What does one do with an item, such as a tallis, which is damaged to the point where it is beyond repair and can no longer be used? Please let me know if your answer can be generalized to other religious articles and books. Thank you for your help.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47914/how-should-holy-objects-be-buried

Comment: related and near duplicates http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14448/11501 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12184/11501

Comment: good survey of original sources for talit and tzitzit http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=138&article=465 - note the halacha for books is completely different, see links above for details