# How to dispose of properly old Haggadot?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, genizah-storage

I've inherited some old Maxwell House haggadot, from the 1980s.  They're in perfect condition, but we simply prefer more modern styled ones now.  What would be a proper and respectful way of getting rid of them?  Some very nice, creative haggadot have come around in recent years that I'm very fond of, and at this point, I prefer these over the old standards.

Comment: There are places (such as schools or old age homes) that can use them. Check in your community.

Comment: ...on the humorous side, you can always just drop them off at my parents' house and they can mix them in with the pile of MH ones and use them for another 40 years(only 40? thought they were older...maybe I'm thinking of the Chase and Sanborn ones)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Hagadas have complete Pesukim they are considered a sacred object. Thus the correct way to dispose of them is to place them in Geniza. [Here is](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47914/how-should-holy-objects-be-buried/47924#47924) a link explaining Geniza.

Comment: This is highly debatable http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/159/759

Comment: @DoubleAA No one is cited on that page as saying such _hagados_ don't require burial.

Comment: @msh210 Yes, because that question didn't specify hagados. But the positions there are reasonably applicable here too. Obviously CYLOR, but this answer's absolute assertions are unwarranted.

Comment: No, @DoubleAA, by "saying" I meant "implying".