# Can I bury my own sheimos?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, funeral-burial-levaya

If I don't want to pay to have someone bury sheimos for me, is it ok to bury them in my backyard? Is there any procedure that I would have to follow as far as how to deep to bury it or any certain tefillos that I have to recite?

Comment: Depending where you live, it might be illegal.

Comment: This is an excellent question I have been wondering for quite some time myself. I have no Jewish community in the area so there's no one around for me to pay to bury my sheimos! I have a drawer that I put them all in. +1 for the nice question.

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47914. I'm not closing it only because I'm _nogea badavar_. cc @DoubleAA

Comment: I have seen people bring shaimos to their parent's burial and bury them, there. I'm unaware that any prayers are said on this. It may be somewhat different when burying a Sefer Torah. I've heard that they make a rather formal service when this happens.